# cannot resolve (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener)

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have added the Google Play dependency, verified this by checking the build.gradle app and it is in there as:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
```

I have synced my gradle file and have cleaned and re-built my project but I am getting an error in the below code:

```
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
```

The solution when hovering over this error is that i should compile 3rd party parameter, this changes my code to the below which is syntax- error free:

```
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
```

My issue is, is it correct in thinking I shouldn't need to do this if I have already imported the google-play services dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it correct in thinking I shouldn't need to do this if I have
>   already imported the google-play services dependency?

`requestLocationUpdates` 3rd parameter is `LocationListener` so make sure UI component is implementing `LocationListener` interface.

Pass class context in which  `LocationListener` interface is implemented as 3rd parameter. like `<Component_Name>.this`